# Maven - how to set the Super POM

Tags: maven

I need to use a company-local Maven repository, and only that. Now, the Super POM contains repo1.maven.org/maven2 - and I want to switch this off.

Now, http://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-the-pom.html says "All POMs extend the Super POM unless explicitly set".

How do I explicitely set it?

(Maven 3.0.4)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm assuming, that by 'local repository' you mean repository available in your company/office, not local repository as in $HOME/.m2/repository.

Define your repository in user's settings.xml file as a mirror of all repositories will do the trick:

```xml
  <settings xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/SETTINGS/1.0.0"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/SETTINGS/1.0.0
                      http://maven.apache.org/xsd/settings-1.0.0.xsd">

      <mirrors>
        <mirror>
          <id>companyrepo</id>
          <url>http://localrepo.com/repo</url>
          <mirrorOf>*</mirrorOf>
        </mirror>
      </mirrors>
  </settings>
```

That way every project will inherit from Super POM but Maven won't connect to repo1.maven.org

Comment: Interestingly this answered my problem, if not my question. (I still don't know how to set a Super POM, but I don't need to anymore :)

Comment: SuperPOM is somewhere inside maven jars, you'd need to find out given jar, modify pom and jar files again. But in my opinion it does not makes sense at all...

Comment: It was the "unless explicitly set" of aforementioned docu that made me believe setting it is the way to go. I stopped that.

Answer (score 0):

My understanding is that the Super POM provides widely-used functionality for all maven POMs, unless that functionality is explicitly provided by the project POM (e.g. a bit like the Object class in Java).

As such, to avoid using the public repositories, you can specify the (local) repository to use in your POM. However, a better way of doing this is to specify the local repositories in a settings.xml file - this allows you to password protect your local repository, without then committing your username/passwords to a source code repository, and sharing them manually.

Answer (score 0):

What you are looking for is Maven's offline mode. You can enable it by `-o` or `--offline` option when using console to call Maven. If you really want to have it enabled all the time, add `<offline>true</offline>` to your `settings.xml`.

Most extreme option, if you can't (for a reason) use offline mode, is to overwrite repository definition of `central` id. Example:

```
<repository>
  <id>central</id>
  <url>file://C:\tmprepo</url>
</repository>
```

I recommend offline mode-based solution. It's clean and clear.

Comment: Sorry, my formulation misled you. I meant to talk about a company local repository, as Tomasz rightly assumed. So offline mode doesnt do it for me.